# Prepopulating an ASP form without code behind from standard HTML page

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic

I've been given a task, which I believe my employer is just putting a carrot in front of me and seeing how far I will run.

A vendor has provided us with a form application. This application is in ASP. My task is to see if its possible to Pre-populate this ASP application because we want to host a little 'mini-wizard' questionnaire on our site and when you click submit on the 'mini-wizard' it pre-populates a few fields on the application.

My first question to him was "Do we have access to the ASP code behind to look for parameters passed via Get/Post. -  NO

I thought, ok, so there is no way to do it. He then said you may be able to do it with javascript. Which I could see if I could put JS on the application page, but I can't do that either.

My final idea would be to make an ajax call for that page, modify the contents and then display it on our site. I am not sure that would even work, have never tried making an AJAX call to an ASP page from a non-asp site.

Can it be done or is this some form of new developer hazing?

Comment: Not sure if I understand fully, but can you not just create your own form and submit to the ASP form using the same form field names?

Comment: Thats what I am going to try. Just create a simple HTML form that posts to the ASP application. I am going to try giving the the field names/IDs of my form to match the field names/IDs of the application form. For some reason I don't see this working though. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. As you are going to use client side ajax, the page will give you nothing but the HTML output of that page. So you just need to know that what parameters you need to pass to that page. Even there might be no need to pass parameters.So, Take an asp page of your own and do the ajax call